# How to upload local library (aar) as part of dependency to Bintray

Tags: android, gradle, bintray

I have 3 transitively dependent projects to upload to bintray from gradle, project 1 & 2 are jar, while project 3 is aar that uses another local aar that we can't put in public repository.

I have uploaded project 1 and 2 to bintray, but am stuck on how to go about the third project.
I have the option of given out the third library to our client to include in there project, but I can't push to bintray because the 3rd project depend on this library.

Is there a way to push it to bintray without adding the third project as dependency, while the project request for the third party library.

Comment: you can use `provided` keyword instead of `compile` when adding it as dependency and  later give the aar as a file to your client while making sure the lib is a required dependency for the 3rd project.

Comment: Thanks Radix, your suggestion worked like charms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Radix suggestion, I was able to push the 3rd project to bintray, I changed to **provided** from **compile** and also change some of the configurations

```
  `configurations {
      provided
   }
   sourceSets {
     main { compileClasspath += configurations.provided }
   }
   dependencies {
     provided '...'
   }`
```

and the user can easily pull from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Bintray is not limited to OSS (or even public) artifacts. You can have a private repository on Bintray with your private aar.

Regarding the public aar that depends on the private one and whether you can remove the dependency, it bowls down to a question is the dependency to the private aar *really* mandatory? Will things break with NoClassDefFound errors if the private aar won't be in the classpath? If yes, the answer is no – you can't distribute the public aar without the dependency. If it's not really mandatory then you need to edit the metadata of the public aar, removing the dependency and you're ready to go.